# Migrating from traditional username/password authentication to WIF

Tags: azure, migration, wif

We've got a few apps that authenticate with the traditional username/password or email/password approach using forms authentication. We would like to slowly migrate these accounts to Windows Identity Foundation (WIF).

Mixing forms authentication with WIF is (for what I've seen) not easy. Basically it comes down to creating an STS to supply claims from the built in database.

If we chose to build another STS for hosting the accounts, are there ways to "merge" accounts from different authentication providers? (i.e. someone is already logged on and wants to merge an additional account from a different authentication provider.)

The idea is that we let customers merge accounts and after that slowly remove the old account database.

Comment: "We would like to slowly migrate these accounts to Windows Identity Foundation (WIF)." - what do you mean with that. WIF is just an API.

Comment: The idea is that someone logs in with their account, get asked to connect an account from a different authentication provider (live, google, yahoo, whatever floats their boat) and once they do that they use their new account for the app and the old one is obsolete. Also, the idea is that someone can use this same technique to connect multiple authentication providers to the same account. (Like it doesn't matter what you use to logon with, we still know its the same user.) Scenarios for this are things like business accounts from ADFS connecting to an account from a different provider.

Comment: Right, but this should give you some background information.

Answer (score 0):

Mixing forms and WIF is not too hard:

http://leastprivilege.com/2012/02/02/mixing-forms-and-token-authentication-in-a-single-asp-net-application/

http://leastprivilege.com/2012/02/02/mixing-forms-and-token-authentication-in-a-single-asp-net-application-the-details/

Comment: These articles focus on mixing forms & wif on different resources, and that is not the case here.